# Spark dataframe foreachPartition: sum the elements using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to partition spark dataframe and sum elements in each partition using pyspark. But I am unable to do this inside a called function "sumByHour". Basically, I am unable to access dataframe columns inside "sumByHour".

Basically, I am partitioning by "hour" column and trying to sum the elements based on "hour" partition. So expected output is: 6,15,24 for 0,1,2 hour respectively. Tried below with no luck.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import pandas as pd

def sumByHour(ip):
    print(ip)

pandasDF = pd.DataFrame({'hour': [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'numlist': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
myschema = StructType(
                    [StructField('hour', IntegerType(), False),
                     StructField('numlist', IntegerType(), False)] 
                  )
 myDf = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF, schema=myschema)
 mydf = myDf.repartition(3, "hour")
 myDf.foreachPartition(sumByHour)
```

I am able to solve this with "window.partitionBy". But I want to know if it can be solved by "foreachPartition".

Thanks in Advance,

Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the code sample it made this easy.  Here's a really simple example modifies you sumByHour code:

```
def sumByHour(ip):
  mySum = 0
  myPartition = ""
  for x in ip:
   mySum += x.numlist
   myPartition = x.hour
  myString = '{}_{}'.format(mySum, myPartition)
  print(myString)

mydf = myDf.repartition(5,"hour") #wait 5 I wanted 3!!!
```

You get almost the expected result:

```
>>> mydf.foreachPartition(sumByHour)
0_
0_
24_2
6_0
15_1
>>>
```

You might ask why partition by '5' and not the '3'?  Well turns out the hash formula used for 3 partitions has collision for (0,1) into the same partition and then has an empty partition.(Bad luck)  So this *will* work but, you only want to use it on an array that will fit into memory.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation. When I execute the above code in Google collab, it doesn't throw any error, but it doesn't print the o/p of myString.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Window` to do that and add the `sumByHour` as a new column.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions, Window

w = Window.partitionBy("hour")

myDf = myDf.withColumn("sumByHour", functions.sum("numlist").over(w))
myDf.show()

+----+-------+---------+
|hour|numlist|sumByHour|
+----+-------+---------+
|   1|      4|       15|
|   1|      5|       15|
|   1|      6|       15|
|   2|      7|       24|
|   2|      8|       24|
|   2|      9|       24|
|   0|      1|        6|
|   0|      2|        6|
|   0|      3|        6|
+----+-------+---------+
```

Comment: I have already solved it with the above method. But I was trying to see if I can make it work through "foreachPartition". Thanks for the reply though.